# problema conceptual en el modelado de una base de datos (Power designer)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas tengo dudas al modelizar una base de datos para correlatividades de materias de una institucion escolar ficticia en un proyecto escolar que estoy haciendo. La consigna me pide hacer un diagrama entidad relacion de para una institucion cualquiera que ayude a llevar un control  de correlatividades. Dependiendo de la institucion, carrera y materias aprobadas del postulante otorga equivalencia total o parcial a las materias de la carrera a la cual se desea inscribir.Teniendo en cuenta que una materia aprobada del postulante puede cubrir de forma total o parcial a mas de una materia de la carrera a la cual se desea inscribir y que el postulante puede venir de otra carrera de la misma institución. No pide los datos del postulante. Ahora para armar el modelo conceptual creé 4 entidades:

**ENTIDAD**--------/-------------**COLUMNAS**
**Instituciones:**  id_inst(pk), nombre_inst
**Carreras:**  id_carrera(pk),nombre_carr
**Materias:** id_materia(pk), nombre_mat
**Equivalencias:**   id_equiv(pk),tipo_equiv,observaciones

Los tipos de datos por ahora no me interesan o como crear las tablas, esa parte es fácil, solo me interesa un modelado correcto que estén donde deben y como poblar las correlatividades (equivalencias). Hata ahora con el power designer tengo el siguiente CDM:

[image: Modelo Conceptual]

Lo hice teniendo en cuenta que una carrera puede estar presente en varias instituciones y una materia en varias carreras, también que una materia puede ser correlativa a varias total o parcialmente. Y cuando lo paso a físico me queda así:

[image: Modelo Físico]

Ahora lo que no termino de entender es como puedo cargar las correlatividades en ese esquema. Sé insertar datos en tablas, consultas y subconsultas básicas, pero no me cierra como cargar que una materia cubre por ejemplo a otra parcialmente y en observaciones un 70%(por dar un ejemplo de carga). Doy unos datos de ejemplo:
El instituto ficticio 1, donde se implementa la base, tiene las carreras A, B y C. La carrera A tiene las materias H1, M2, M3...Mn. La carrera B tiene las materias H1, J2 J3...Jn y la carrera C tiene  las materias J2, J3, L1, L2 ...Ln. Por otro lado el instituto ficticio 2 tiene las mismas carreras,con solo algunas materias iguales pero mucho menos contenido. Algunas correlatividades concarreras del mismo instituto serían H1(A&B)-total, J2(B&C)-parcial, J3(B&C)-total. Y un ejemplo con el Instituto 2 sería H1(C) del I2 cubriendo parcialmente a H1(A&B) del instituto 1.

Comment: No entiendo dices `una` institución y luego hablas de varias instituciones. Además, a que te refieres con `correlatividades ` ?

Comment: hablo de varias instituciones porque el sistema lo implementaria una institucion cualquiera pero las carreras correlativas o equivalentes pueden ser de varias instituciones. Por ejemplo si yo tuviera aprobada la materia matematica aplicada 2 de la carrera analista de sistemas deberia cubrirme totalmente la materia matemática aplicada 1 de la carrera desarrollador de software tanto de la misma institucion como si fuera de otra institucion. Correlatividad es a lo que yo le digo equivalencia lo tomo como sinónimo (aunque puede no serlo) significa que el contenido de una materia aprueba el de otra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El modelo de datos que planteas podrías representarlo de una forma simplificada así:

[image: Modelo ER]

En donde esa relación de equivalencias es de grado uno y únicamente tienes que registrar el porcentaje de compatibilidad entre las materias que estimes conveniente. El resto se presumirán 0% compatibles.

A partir de los datos de un alumno en una institución, podrías obtener el grado de compatibilidad que tendría con todas las carreras del resto de instituciones con una única consulta, bastante compleja, eso sí.

Implementa físicamente la base de datos, registra unos datos de muestra lo más reales que puedas para poder hacer comprobaciones y, si encuentras dificultades, te hecho una mano con esa consulta.

Casi lo tenías, pero con bucles innecesarios, te sobran varios campos en las relaciones. Por otra parte, más que relación de equivalencia, yo hablaría más de **inclusión**, puesto que el sentido importa: la materia A puede incluir la B, pero la B únicamente un porcentaje de la A. La equivalencia sería el caso particular del 100% en ambos sentidos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta ahí logré una base mucho más sencilla muchas gracias!